# No such file or directory error in node js even though files are in same directiry

Tags: node.js

I have created two-three files in the same directory and then tried to run node server. However, this error  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open about.html ... is coming up. I searched here and tried npm init method but they didn't work. All the files are in the same directory.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const aboutPage = fs.readFileSync('about.html');
const contactPage = fs.readFileSync('contact.html');
const homePage = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    console.log(request.url);

    if(request.url === '/about'){
        return response.end(aboutPage);
    } else if(request.url === '/contact'){
        return response.end(contactPage);
    } else if(request.url === '/'){
        return response.end(homePage);
    } else {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end('No page found');
    }


})

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: can you try fs.readFileSync('./about.html')?

Comment: Still giving me the same error!

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use following code 
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");


http.createServer(function(request, response) 
{ 
if(request.url === "/index"){
fs.readFile("index.html", function (err, data) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.write(data);
response.end();
 });
 }

}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to resolve the path relative the file that you are in.

Otherwise the path will be relative to the current directory, `process.cwd()`

Try this:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const aboutPage = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'about.html'));
```